# Why do people need to be SO anonymous online... for LEGAL reasons?

Tags: help

I don't quite understand this. If you didn't want to have the NSA or whatever spying on you why not just use a VPN? I use PIA and  get a 2mbps speed. Why don't people use something like that instead?

I cannot imagine what people need tor for unless they are doing **illegal** means. I mean sure it is much better then a VPN but is it REALLY worth a 10KBPS speed?

and on another note, does anyone know average speed of it? It took me about 5 minutes to load one photo so I don't think my 10kbps is far off.

Comment: And who owns your VPN...?

Comment: Your question is very opinion-based and attracts also speculative answers. Please try to split it into useful questions which can be answered without much speculation. I'll close this question.

Answer (score 1):

My speed varies, although I've never quite gone down to 10kbps.

In my opinion, to understand the legal uses of anonymity online you need to re-define your outlook on 'legal'. In some countries what you would consider basic rights are considered illegal. in today's age a great deal of information about the outside world can be obtained online. Imagine how different Hitler's rise would have been if the German people had access to a completely anonymous way to gain information from multiple sources without fear of the SS (my history might be a bit off there, but you get the idea)

Outside of that, you also have military uses. While you may not be overly bothered if your next door neighbor knows your looking at cat pictures, in a military/political situation information is vitally important. Going back to history here, you could compare Tor in the military (although I'm not sure if they actually use tor itself) to the German enigma machine used in WW2.

Past those more serious issues, you still have the issue of basic privacy. I personally don't like the idea of my government/neighbor peering in on what I'm doing online, especially when I'm doing something which while legal, might not be morally correct.

Anonymity gives people the ability to say what they think, without fear of IRL backlash. My opinions on certain subjects are not always what my peers believe them to be, and anonymity gives me the security to express my thoughts.

EDIT: Anonymity is the key to true free speech.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just being a cypherpunk
2. Access region-restricted material via different exit nodes
3. Hidden services

I run 4 exits (pay out of my pocket) BTW. However, I think that Tor
needs a huge redesign in its ideology/infrastructure, closer to BitTorrent
with more P2P functions, IPv6, scalability, and resilience.

Comment: HORNET seems to address these redesign issues.

Answer (score 0):

It's not all about NSA/GCHQ.  The spooks get all the headlines, but there is a vast commercial industry devoted to tracking your every move, for their own profit.

That's how Target knows your daughter is pregnant before you do, how that website knows you shop at Whole Foods.  Your IP address can be correlated with your identity, which is correlated (via freely-available government tax records) of the address and value of your house, which suggests your income, which makes you a (un)desirable advertising target.

Contra those I-have-nothing-to-hide types, we *all* have plenty to hide.  I don't want to live in a fishbowl, and I use Tor to frustrate those entities that want just that.

Oh, and about your VPN?  That's putting all your eggs in one basket. When your vendor gets hacked your identity (credit card) and IP address of origin will be linked and potentially everything you've done via VPN will be exposed for all to see.  Don't tell me your vendor's business records won't get p0wned.  If the last few years have taught us anything, it is that *no* entity, be it governmental, commercial, or residential is safe from a determined team of hackers.

Comment: yes but would it really matter if they were spying... unless you were doing something illegal? like beating off to children or buying drugs?

Answer (score 0):

It's not just the NSA that does intelligence gathering on individuals. The entire web does this all so. For an example Google tracks literally every thing about you to try and improve their business. This includes the people you know and who you don't know. Where you work. Who your dating. If your getting married or might be. What your hobbies are. What your phone and email are. They all so scan all your emails like almost all of them do and report to the FBI and such. Literally every thing about you that is posted online and that you look at is being tracked by some thing analytical or intelligence gathering for tons of different reasons. Some people just don't want any one knowing a lot of this information because literally it isn't the government or Googles business if your planning on getting married or having a baby or the last 1,000s of pages looked at people talked to.

People don't just choose anon services because they do illegal thinks but rather because privacy doesn't exist in our lives any more and people enjoy privacy from government and business entities. When you can log on facebook and track this persons entire life it's not really a good thing. Some employers even check facebook and other sites to make hiring choices and see what kind of person you are. Not to mention that you can type your name and age and city in a search engine to find yourself in a public database pulling up a listing of the last 10 plus places you lived phone numbers family and people you know. Your and their aliases, criminal history, marriage and divorce records and just tons and tons of other very very very personal crap that is very private and sensitive information. You don't tell every one you meet all your addresses, friends, and relatives. Why should we be able to find this online for free.

To figure out how fast your speed is your going to have to figure out how many proxy sites and such your running your connection through and take them in to consideration all so.